# Comparing arrays, point me in the right direction please

Tags: php, arrays

So what im trying to do is compare bank transactions to orders in my database and if they match change the order status to confirmed.

The transactions come in a xml format

```
$transaction->user-number //this is the social security number of the one who made the transaction
$transaction->amount //this is the amount transfered
```

I need to compare the user-number to the user-numbers associated with orders in my database.
I could do that by making two arrays with those numbers and use `array_intersect` to find the numbers that are present in both the database and in the transactions xml.

Now i would have the user-numbers of the ones who have made a transaction but I still need to see if they transfered the correct amount.

I will be able to finish this but I somehow feel that there is a simpler solution by using the user-number as the index in the array and the amount as the value and create two arrays like that and compare them.

Can anyone help me here before I write some complicated, slow and messy code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you on the right track:

```
class Order
{

    private $user = null;
    private $amt = null;

    public function __construct($user, $amt)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->amt = $amt;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function equals($transaction)
    {
        if ($this->user == $transaction->usernumber &&
                $this->amt == $transaction->amount) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

// an empty array to hold the completed orders
$completed = array();

// loop over orders
foreach($orders as $order) {

    // create a new order object
    $order = new Order($order->user, $order->amount);

    // loop over all transactions
    foreach($transactions as $transaction) {

        // if transactions is equal to our order then
        // add it to the list of completed orders
        if($order->equals($transaction)) {
            $completed[] = $order;
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a small wrapper class for all your orders then allows you to compare an order to a transaction as your described it above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but after rethinking this I went for a different approach.